# Firebase Performance Monitoring for WebView

Tags: android, firebase, webview, android-webview, firebase-performance

I have WebView in my Android app.

The Performance of URLs that are loaded in the WebView is not shown in Firebase Performance Monitoring Dashboard. I have also checked the 'Network' tab in the Performance Monitoring dashboard.

Plus, I enabled debugging for Firebase Performance and there too the Network requests were not being tracked.

So, what should I do (preferably with minimal code) to track the response times, payload size, success rates and other metrics of the network requests that happen in WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Performance Monitoring only captures HTTP requests made by Java/Kotlin code compiled into your app.  It doesn't track anything made by system components, such as WebView.  If you want to track something manually, you can [use its API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#manual-network), but you'll have to figure out how to collect that data yourself.